# Angular 5, Observable and async function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular5, observable

I have been trying to create a function that is similar to http.get(...) but not doing any http. Basically what I have done is that I defined a function

```
async myFunc(): Observable<string> {
 var myObservable: Observable<string>;

  //.....
  // the rest of the function's code comes here
  // ...

 return myObservable;
}
```

But I always get an error that it is not compatible with ES5/ES3 and should return a Promise object? But I am wondering how it became possible with Angular 5's http.get function? Where clearly it returns an Observable.

Thanks,
Artanis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async/await functionality works with promises. You can use `Observable.defer` to define an Observable with async/await functionality.

See this post for more information: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try this one and will update you after.

Comment: I was trying your suggestion, but I was wondering how do I access the fields of the enclosing objects? Thanks.

Comment: Consider asking a new question and elaborating with some example code as to what "enclosing objects" you are referring to so we can better help.

Comment: thanks for your patience. Yes, I have created a new question. I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690433/angular-5-accessing-the-fields-that-is-enclosing-the-observable