# Angular 5 accessing the fields that is enclosing the Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, observable

Hi Angular and Typescript gurus,

I have been exploring how to make an Observable to be Asynchronous.
Somebody did advice to try this link:
https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

And I am facing 2 problems with this example:
- How to access the fields of the class enclosing the Observable
- How do I do .next(), .error() or .complete for the observer

Here is a sample/pseudo class

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class TestComponent {

    private isRunning: boolean = false;

    construct() {
       this.createObservable()
         .subscribe(
            data => {
               console.log("observable sent: " + data);
            }
            ,error => {
               console.log("observable had an error:");
               console.log(error);
            }
         );

       console.log("If the observable above is asynchronous this will be executed before the observable ends...");

       //for some random event here terminate the observable
       while(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) != 6073){ }
       this.isRunning = false;
    }

    private createObservable():Observable<string> {
        this.isRunning = true;
        var obs: Observable<string> = Observable.defer(async function() {
           while(this.isRunning) { //accessing this.isRunning here is an error
             console.log("Observable is still running");
             setTimeout(() => { }, 2000);
             //main logic of the observable goes here...
           }

           //for some event I want to do a
           //observer.next("test string");

           //if an error occurs I want to do a
           //observer.error()

           //after some time... I will need to a
           //observer.complete()
        });

        return obs;
     }

}
```

Follow-up question, is this a proper way to make an asynchronous observable manually?
Or probably, do I have the right mindset that every observable is asynchronous.
Because when I was creating the same class here but the Observable object/class is based on "`import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs';`" it wasn't running asynchronously.

By the way, my example above is based on This one is based on `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Your expertise is very much appreciated.

many thanks


Artanis.

Comment: `Obserable`'s are asynchronous data streams,  check out this website http://reactivex.io/. Also since rxjs version 6, your imports should be from `rxjs` for `Observable` related stuff, for operators, you import from `rxjs/operators`. And **asynchronous observable** like how you are saying sounds **strange**

Comment: @Dummy thanks for your answer. I was actually expecting here that `console.log("If the observable above is asynchronous this will be executed before the observable ends...");` will be executed even before the Observable finishes. But what happens on my code here is that everything is just being executed synchronously. I was a bit disappointed because I really thought Observables are asynchronous.

Comment: You are not using the `Observable.defer` API correctly, check out the docs [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer). To preserve the `this` reference, either assign it to a local variable or use arrow function, don't use `function` keyword to pass your callback, it changes the `this` reference based on which context it is invoked in, that is why you get the compilation error

Comment: @Dummy, noted. but follow-up question. How come this line: `console.log("If the observable above is asynchronous this will be executed before the observable ends...");` will be executed after the observable finishes executing? I was expecting this to be executed before the observable finishes its loop.

Comment: It is because (Fromy understanding) is that `Observale.defer` expects a function that returns an `Observable` (As the docs says, **observable factory function**), but here, you are not returning anything, so by default, `undefined` is returned which when you call `subscribe` on, it completes **synchronously** which makes it a **synchronous** observable

Comment: @Dummy, I tried what you recommended and it worked. It became somehow concurrent (although concurrency is not officially supported in Javascript/Typescript)